# Out-of-Proc-COM-Server (x86): dllhost.exe looks in wrong registry path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, 32bit-64bit

I write for a COM-Server (x86) a wrapper based on a DLL surrogate (x64) described like [here](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) to get access from a 64-bit-client.

I registered the COM-Server (x86) and the Proxy/Stub-DLL (x86) and they registered in the WOW6432-Nodes.

But when I call the instance with

```
IShellServerx86* pShellServer = NULL;
::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CShellServerx86), NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER |
                   CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER, __uuidof(IShellServerx86),
                   (void**)&pShellServer);
```

the dllhost.exe is started and I get back "Class not registered". When I analyse the dllhost.exe (x86-version!) with procmon I can see that the dllhost.exe tries to look up the paths in the 64bit-registry and not in the WOW6432-Nodes.

I tried to dupliate the registry entries into the 64-bit-paths but then I get back "%1 is not a WIN32 application".

How can I can COM to look up in the 32-bit paths? Is the flag "CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER" not enough?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Tobias

EDIT:

I found at MSDN [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384235%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) article that told that with Windows 7 registry reflection is disabled? It is said that all CLSIDs that contains a InprocServer32-Key are not reflected. But how then can I achieve reflection when I use System-Surrogation?

Comment: Hmm, should work.  Try the code sample in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/f2c10d58-ec35-4e7c-99dd-3d6c71c30112

Comment: Thanks for the link. But then I have to change to an EXE-COM-Server. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with Windows 7 they disabled redirection for CLSIDs which includes InprocServer32-keys because they assumed that these are 32-bit DLLs and cannot be loaded. And so this [article](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) is not for 64-bit versions of Windows 7.